# Issue accessing Azure APIs in Visual Studio Code

Tags: azure-api-management

[image]

Hi community,

I am having issues while accessing Azure APIs in Visual Studio Code. Whenever, I expand the APIs region, I get thrown this error. I want to debug the API policies but this is blocking me. Any solutions to this ?

PS. This problem isn't happening at other subscription where there aren't any APIs except Echo API (auto generated by Azure)

Tried Restarting Visual Studio Code
Tried clearing Visual Studio Data and getting it reinstalled